# The elements in an array seems to be changing, array's first half sorted and second half is randomized

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting

This program is designed to give out randomized numbers depending on how many the user inputs as the size of array. The `rand()` is working and gives outputs elements depending on the user.

The problem is when it comes to the part where it is getting sorted the elements of the array seems to be changing from a different value.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int SizeArray = 0;
int setArray[] = { NULL };
int  tempA, half;

int main() {
  cout << "Enter number of elements: ";
  cin >> SizeArray;

  srand(time(0));
  for (int i = 0; i < SizeArray; i++) {
    setArray[i] = 51 + rand() % (100 - 51);
  }
    
  cout << "\n\n\nraw input  " << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < SizeArray; i++) {
    cout << setArray[i] << "\t";
  }

  half = SizeArray / 2;
  cout << "\n\n\nfirst half  " << endl;
  for (int j = 0; j < half; j++){
    for (int i = 0; i < half; i++){
      if (setArray[i] > setArray[i + 1]){
        tempA = setArray[i];
        setArray[i] = setArray[i + 1];
        setArray[i + 1] = tempA;
      }
    }
  }
            
  for (int i = 0; i < half; i++){ //to print the sorted array
    cout << setArray[i] << "\t";
  }

  cout << "\n\n\nsecond half  " << endl;
  for (int i = half; i < SizeArray; i++){ //to print the second half 
    cout << setArray[i] << "\t";
  }

  cout << "\n\n\nmerge " << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < SizeArray; i++) { //to print all elements of the array
    cout << setArray[i] << "\t";
  }
}
```

[example of error there should be no "4" there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3I4B.png)

I'm hoping to know why the elements are changing and what are some possible solutions for it.

Comment: VTC as a typo because you simply never allocated the array elements that you index to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int setArray[] = { NULL };` creates an array with *one* element. If you try accessing anything but `setArray[0]` you have undefined behavior, which is what you see.

Since the number of elements aren't known at compile-time, use a `std::vector<int>` instead.

```
#include <vector>

// ...

std::vector<int> setArray;
```

Then, when the user has entered how many elements there should be, do:

```
setArray.resize(SizeArray);
```

---

An unrelated matter is that you don't actually take any input from the user. In your *input* loop, you print the values already present:

```
cout << "\n\n\nraw input  " << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < SizeArray; i++) {
  cout << setArray[i] << "\t";         // cin >> setArray[i]   ???
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, about the "raw input"  that was a mistake, what I mean there was to show the numbers/ elements generated from the `rand()` without any changes.

Comment: @DeWard You're welcome! Regarding the raw input: Aha, yes, I see what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Your program has undefined behavior.

The line

```
int setArray[] = { NULL };
```

creates an array with one element. Accessing elements from it with any index higher than 0 causes undefined behavior.

You need to create a dynamically allocated array. My suggestion is to use a `std::vector<int>`.

```
// Move themm inside main.
// int SizeArray = 0;
// int setArray[] = { NULL };
// int  tempA, half;

int main()
{
    int SizeArray = 0;
    int  tempA, half;

    cout << "Enter number of elements: ";
    cin >> SizeArray;

    // Construct a vector with size SizeArray.
    std::vctor<int> setArray(SizeArray);

    // Rest of your program.
```